# Threads associated with the same process

Tags: multithreading, process

Hi guys im having trouble finding the answer to this question. I think the answer is C but wanted to double check if i was correct. Thanks.

Which ONE of the following statements is FALSE.
Threads associated with the same process are able to ...
2
(a) control their associated process.
(b) run in parallel.
(c) block themselves.
(d) access data in other processes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd guess the answer they're after is (d). The other answers are clearly true. Since each process has its own address space, threads in one process can't directly access data in another process. To do such communication, you typically start by moving the data *out* of one process, such as putting it into a pipe or FIFO.

Answer (score 0):

a. If threads can't control their associated process, who can (since everything in a process is a thread)?

b. If they couldn't run in parallel, what's the point? :)

c. If they couldn't block themselves, they couldn't use IPC primitives like muteness and semaphores.

d. If they could access data in other processes, what would be the distinction between a threads associated with one process or a different one?